# How to integrate pow()/** with custom class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have made a matrix class with python just for practise and I want to achieve something like:

```
M1=Matrix(elements)
print(M1**3)
```

I have already defined method for multiplication.
This is the error that I get when I try to do it:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Matrix' and 'int'
```

I know that I can make a method to achieve this but  is there any way so that '**' can be used?

Here is the class for reference.
(I know the code might not be efficient, its just a practise)

```
class Matrix:

    '''A list based matrix class'''

    def __init__(self,rows):

        #rows is a 2-d list ex. [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
        
        self.rows=rows
        self.columns=self.get_cols()

        if not(self.valid()):
            raise ValueError("Some incomplete rows are present")
       
        else:
            self.order=(len(self.rows),len(self.columns))

    def valid(self):
        lenght=len(self.rows[0])      
        for i in self.rows:
            if not (len(i) == lenght):
                return False
        else:
            return True
     
    def get_cols(self):
        cols=[]
        for row in self.rows:
            for j in range(len(row)):
                try:
                    cols[j].append(row[j])
                except IndexError:
                    cols.append([row[j]])
        return cols

    def __mul__(self,other):
        if(type(self) is type(other)):
            #MATRIX MULTIPLICATION
            if(self.order[1] == other.order[0]):
                prod=[[] for i in range(self.order[0])]
                
                for row in range(len(self.rows)):
                    for col in range(len(other.columns)):
                        sum=0
                        for i in range(len(self.rows[row])):
                            sum+=self.rows[row][i]*other.columns[col][i]
                        prod[row].append(sum)
                return Matrix(prod)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Can't multiply 2 matrices with different inner dimensions")

        elif(type(other) is int or type(other) is float):
            #scalar multiplication
            for i in range(len(self.rows)):
                for j in range(len(self.rows[i])):
                    self.rows[i][j]*=other
            return self

        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Can't multiply with {type(other)}")
```

Thank You!

Comment: ```pow()``` or ```**``` is nothing but repeated multiplication. Write your own ```power``` function and do it.

Comment: @Ram "I know that I can make a method to achieve this but is there any way so that '**' can be used?"

Comment: Are you asking if there is a special method name for the power function?? Did you check the documentation? - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Answer (score 1):

The same way as you have done with multiplication, but use `__pow__` instead of `__mul__`. You can do the same will all other operators too, they can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of what you are trying to accomplish. Firstly the matrix should be copied to avoid modifying the original (notice that M1 is unmodified). Also since you are trying to print your matrix, I added a __str__ method (__repr__ also would effectively accomplish the same thing).

Edit: Thanks to chepner for pointing out NotImplementedError.

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Matrix:

    # the rest of your class

    def __pow__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, int):
            raise NotImplementedError("Only raise a matrix to an integer power")
        new_matrix = Matrix(deepcopy(self.rows))
        for _ in range(other-1):
            new_matrix = new_matrix * self
        return new_matrix

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rows)
```

Test it with the following.

```
M1=Matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
M2=M1**3
print(M1)
print(M2)
```

Comment: Rather than using `assert`, return `NotImplemented` if `other` is anything *except* an `int`.

Comment: `assert` is a debugging tool that can be disabled at runtime.